# Dynamically get a list of Laravel Validation Rules?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Is there any way to dynamically retrieve a list of "legal" validation rules?  I'm trying to have my models self-validate their own validation rule string, to make sure it is accurate.  i.e. to make sure someone didn't type "requierd".

I see getRules() at http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Validation.Validator.html, but that only returns ruled used within the validation, not a list of all known rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official API to do this, so you'll need to use reflection.  If you look at the implementation of the `validate` method, you'll see that rules are simply methods on the validate object (that's returned from the static call to `make`)

```
#File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php
protected function validate($attribute, $rule)
{
    //...
    $method = "validate{$rule}";

    if ($validatable && ! $this->$method($attribute, $value, $parameters, $this))
    {
        $this->addFailure($attribute, $rule, $parameters);
    }
    //...
}
```

This means we can use reflection to grab a list of validate rules.  Also, the method names are camel case with a leading capital letter ("studly case" in laravel speak) so we'll need to lower-case/underscore them ("snake case" in laravel speak) to get the actual validation rule name.  We'll also identify which rules have `:` parameters.  Unfortunately, there's no way to derive **what** each rule expects the parameter to be.

```
$validator = Validator::make(array(), array());

//
$r = new ReflectionClass($validator);
$methods = $r->getMethods();  

//filter down to just the rules
$methods = array_filter($methods, function($v){        
    if($v->name == 'validate') { return false; }
    return strpos($v->name, 'validate') === 0;
});

//get the rule name, also if it has parameters
$methods = array_map(function($v){
    $value = preg_replace('%^validate%','',$v->name); 
    $value = Str::snake($value);

    $params = $v->getParameters();
    $last   = array_pop($params);
    if($last && $last->name == 'parameters')
    {
        $value .= ':[params]';    
    }
    return Str::snake($value);
}, $methods);

var_dump($methods);
```

If a user has added validation rules by extending the validation class, this technique will pickup any custom methods.  However, if a user has extended the validation class with the `Validation::extend` syntax, the technique above will not find those rule.  To get those rules, you'll need to do something like this.

```
Validator::extend('customrule',function($attribute, $value, $parameters){
});

Validator::extend('anothercustom', 'FooValidator@validate');

$validator = Validator::make(array(), array());

$extension_methods = array();
foreach($validator->getExtensions() as $value=>$callback)
{
    if(is_string($callback))
    {
        list($class, $method) = explode('@', $callback);
        $r = new ReflectionClass($class);
        $method = $r->getMethod($method);
    }
    else if(is_object($callback) && get_class($callback) == 'Closure')
    {
        $method = new ReflectionFunction($callback);
    }

    $params = $method->getParameters();
    $last   = array_pop($params);
    if($last && $last->name == 'parameters')
    {
        $value .= ':[params]';    
    }
    $extension_methods[] = $value;

}
```

Comment: BTW, would this include custom methods, or just the ones that come by default?

Comment: @Anthony Update the answer.  The first technique would catch custom rules added from extending the base validator class, but it wouldn't have caught rules added via `extend`.  I've updated the question with more reflection code to grab those custom rules as well.